# How to drop float values from a column - pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe given shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'subject_id':[1,1,1,1,1,1],
  'val' :[5,6.4,5.4,6,6,6]
 })
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to drop the `values` from `val` column which ends with `.[1-9]`. Basically I would like to retain values like `5.0`,`6.0` and drop values like `5.4`,`6.4` etc

Though I tried below, it isn't accurate

```
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(int)
df.drop_duplicates()  # it doesn't give expected output and not accurate.
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Both the answers below are really good and easy to understand.However I can mark only one answer and I mark @Jezrael answer for detailed explanation and diiferent ways to get to the output. Nonetheless, Allen's answer is also good and useful to know. Thank you both for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First idea is compare original value with casted column to integer, also assign integers back for expected output (integers in column):

```
s = df['val']
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(int)

df = df[df['val'] == s]
print (df)
   subject_id  val
0           1    5
3           1    6
4           1    6
5           1    6
```

Another idea is test `is_integer`:

```
mask = df['val'].apply(lambda x: x.is_integer())
df['val'] = df['val'].astype(int)

df = df[mask]
print (df)

   subject_id  val
0           1    5
3           1    6
4           1    6
5           1    6
```

If need floats in output you can use:

```
df1 = df[ df['val'].astype(int) == df['val']]
print (df1)
   subject_id  val
0           1  5.0
3           1  6.0
4           1  6.0
5           1  6.0
```

Comment: If you don't need to transform 'val' to int, You could pass using the `s` and just use `df = df[df['val'] == df['val'].astype(int)]`

Comment: @Aryerez - I know, but reason is for integer output in `val` column.

Answer (score 4):

Use mod 1 to determine the residual. If residual is 0 it means the number is a int. Then use the results as a mask to select only those rows.

```
df.loc[df.val.mod(1).eq(0)].astype(int)

    subject_id  val
0   1           5
3   1           6
4   1           6
5   1           6
```